# Alert toggles every time when the input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input and it toggles a function if it's been changed. I also have table that is created dynamically. And each row in table has an addButton. So, the problem is that this `alert` toggles so many times so I change the input, but I need to toggle it only once. How to deal with it?

```
$('.inputsearchform').bind('input', function() {
  var addButton = $(".fa.fa-plus");
  addButton.click(function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

I don't need to add click event to this button, but I need to get onclick() event from it. But this code is only working way, that I found. By the way, I need to get this event only if button is clicked, not every time that I change input.

**Question** How to check `onclick` event on button, that appears dynmically, when the `input` changes?

I tried to add onclick event `<i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addButtonF()">`
and in js file: `function addButtonF(){
    alert("test");
}`

but I have an error `addButtonF is not defined`.

Comment: What do you mean by _" but I need to toggle it only once."_ ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you be more accurate, maybe add html code? Your code says: on each input change add new click event to addButton. That means: if you change input 3 times, than you bind click event 3 times and you get 3 alerts.

Comment: Is expected result for `click` event of `.fa.fa-plus` to be called at each `input` event ? Requirement is not clear

Comment: @guest271314 `addButton` appears only if I write something in input. I need to use alert only if I click on this button, not every time that I change input.

Comment: _"`addButton` appears only if I write something in input. I need to use alert only if I click on this button, not every time that I change input."_ Yes, you can use event delegation to achieve this. See updated post

Comment: Is an element created and appended to `document` at each `input` event ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, table is generated at every `input` changing event. I tried `$(document).on("click", ".fa.fa-plus", function(){` but `alert` didn't appear.

Comment: @LevS _" I tried `$(document).on("click", ".fa.fa-plus", function(){` but `alert` didn't appear"_ Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 Unfortunatelly, I can't, because table is created from `MySQL` database, using `NodeJS`

Comment: @LevS There was a syntax error at original Answer. `'fa fa-plus'` should be quoted at element creation; See stacksnippets at updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A start would be to define `click` outside of `input` handler to prevent multiple `click` handler calls at each `click` of `addButton`

> So, the problem is that this alert toggles so many times so I change
>   the input, but I need to toggle it only once.

Not clear from Question which element needs to be toggled once, or which function should only be called once ?

> `addButton` appears only if I write something in input. I need to use
>   alert only if I click on this button, not every time that I change
>   input.

Use event delegation to attach event to dynamically created elements having `className` `.fa.fa-plus`

```js
$(".inputsearchform").bind("input", function() {
   // create dynamic element
   $("<table class='fa fa-plus'>")
   .html("<tr><td>" 
     + $(".fa.fa-plus").length 
     + "</td></tr>"
   ).appendTo("body");          
});

$(document).on("click", ".fa.fa-plus", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="inputsearchform">
```

---

Substitute [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) for `class` which does not set `className` of element; use latest version of jQuery

```js
$(".inputsearchform").bind("input", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  div.appendChild(table);
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(tr);
  var td = tr.insertCell(0);
  td.innerHTML = "test";   
  td.className = "try"
});

$(document).on("click", ".try", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="inputsearchform">
<div id="div"></div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1x8ja6qe/2/

Comment: Object with this class is created dynamically, only if I type something in input. So, I can't do it

Comment: You forget the table is dynamically created. We do not know if there is one or more add-buttons, are input fields also added dynamically, etc.

Comment: _"Object with this class is created dynamically, only if I type something in input."_ No object appears to be created at `js` at Question, `addButton` refers to same element

Comment: @skobaljic _"You forget the table is dynamically created."_ Where are elements created dynamically at `js` at Question ?

Comment: The code is not in the question, but he said: ` I also have table that is created dynamically. And each row in table has an addButton.`. The question must be improved.

Comment: @guest271314 It doesn't work `$(...).on is not a function`

Comment: @LevS _"It doesn't work `$(...).on is not a function`"_ Is `jQuery` defined ? Have you wrapped `js` at Answer within `$(document).ready(function() {})` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it's defined in HTML before this script.

Comment: @LevS You should create and include a stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LevS See updated post , https://jsfiddle.net/1x8ja6qe/2/; substituted `className` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className for `class` which does not set `className` of element, used lastest version of jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/1x8ja6qe/ used version `1.6.4`

Comment: @LevS Does updated post, jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1x8ja6qe/2/ return expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, thanks for help! I accepted your answer, but I can't upvote it ;(